# What's the difference between PE32+ and PE32?

Tags: c#, .net, portable-executable, corflags

When running [CorFlags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) on some DLL file, some show as PE32 and some show as PE32+. What's the difference?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The PE32 format stands for Portable Executable 32-bit, while PE32+ is Portable Executable 64-bit format.

Please see this [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20120904152354/http://radialix.com/index.php/radialix-overview/73-win32) for detailed info.

Answer (score 18):

The flags interpretation:

Any CPU: PE = PE32 and 32BIT = 0

x86: PE = PE32 and 32BIT = 1

64-bit: PE = PE32+ and 32BIT = 0

Answer (score 14):

Here's a more complete list of architecture build options and the corresponding corflags output for the relevant fields:

```
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
                      PE     32BITREQ  32BITPREF 
─────────────────────────────────────────────────
 x86                  PE32          1          0 
 AnyCPU               PE32          0          0 
 AnyCPU prefer 32bit  PE32          0          1 
 x64                  PE32+         0          0 
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
```